# facing an issue while creating a next.js build on ubuntu - webpack error

Tags: node.js, linux, next.js

I am trying to build next.js app on ubuntu LTS 18.0
with node 14.18.0
also tried with node 16
but no luck!

```
yarn run v1.22.15
$ next build
info  - Loaded env from /home/name/heb/HEB-IOT-UI/.env
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
info  - Checking validity of types  
warn  - No ESLint configuration detected. Run next lint to begin setup
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
Failed to compile.

node:fs
Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:fs" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.


> Build error occurred
Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
    at /home/name/heb/HEB-IOT-UI/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:397:19
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/home/name/heb/HEB-IOT-UI/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:60:20)
    at async Object.build [as default] (/home/name/heb/HEB-IOT-UI/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:77:25)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a `node:fs` error recently, which was resolved by going back to an even older version of Node. Perhaps try the following:

```
nvm install 12.14.1
nvm use 12.14.1
```

You may also want to try using a different version of NPM. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Updated 12.14.6 to 12.14.1